# Trying to access labels from UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have created a .xib file that has a bunch of labels in it to be used with [SwipeView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView) . My problem is that I can't/don't know how to access and change their text after loading the view:

```
let newView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("SwipeHelperView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as UIView

for (var subview) in newView.subviews
{           
    if (subview.isKindOfClass(UILabel) && subview.tag == 0)
    {
        subview.text = "asdaS" //ERROR: cannot assign 'text' in 'subview'
    }                
}
```

Would it be easier to create the labels on spot, something like this:

```
var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
label.center = CGPointMake(0, 0)
label.text = "some text"
newView.addSubview(label)
```

rather than trying to access them from the "newView" UIView ? Is there a 'recommended' way or it's about prefferences ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should cast it:

```
let newView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("SwipeHelperView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as UIView

for subview in newView.subviews as [UIView]
{           
    if subview.tag == 0
    {
        if let label = subview as? UILabel {
            label.text = "asdaS"
        }
    }                
}
```

If you set a custom tag (e.g 333) you can get it as it:

```
if let label = newView.viewWithTag(333) as? UILabel {
    label.text = "TEST"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are fine but depends on your goal that you want to achieve. You could do as follow :-

1. You could create property and connect your label from xib. Later in your code you could change it's text as below:-

   @IBOutlet var usernameLabel: UILabel!
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       self.usernameTxt?.text = "some text"
   }
2. You could programmatically create and add it to your view as subView. Code:-

   var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(FRAME))
   label.text = "some text"
   youView.addSubview(label)

Answer (score 0):

```
it will be helpful if you make labels programmatically and add it in your newView.
```

var subview

```
   for subview:AnyObject in newView.subviews
   {

    if (subview.isKindOfClass(UILabel) && subview.tag == 0)
    {
     var label=subview as UILabel
     label.text="some text"
    }                
   }
```